# Real time CSS updates in Chrome When Editing From Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, google-chrome

Whenever my colleague makes changes to his .css files in his Visual Studio (2015) chrome automatically detects the change and updates the website styling, it looks very useful.

The same does not happen for me in my Visual Studio (2017) but it did in my initial computer setup (a few win 10 re-installs ago) when I used VS 2015. Is this a disabled feature in 2017, is it anything to do with VS at all? neither of us have any idea why it works in his set up and not mine

I have come across a youtube video of this behaviour:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reAw8_FGWpE

Comment: Are you building ASP.Net Core apps? I ask because you might want to read about the `dotnet watch run` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch).

Comment: We aren't in this case but I will have a look anway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found it! This is a feature called

"Enable CSS Auto-Sync"

Its part of the "Browser Link" functionality which is shown here:

https://webtooling.visualstudio.com/project-system/browser-link/#css-auto-sync

To make use of it, you have to enable "Browser Link" and I think it only works in the last tab you opened. You can figure out which tab its linked to by hitting the button as a refresh and seeing which tab refreshes :). (You can also open the Browser Link Dashboard to view active connections)

Comment: The setting looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691944/how-do-i-re-enable-real-time-css-editing-in-visual-studio#46692826.  I also I had to switch off "Enable Reload on Save" to make the changes I was making smooth and real-time.

Comment: I watched a video from Mads: https://youtu.be/kkKBqNJaylU
I have used **CSS Auto-Sync**, do you know If there is a way to edit css files in the browser and then have the changes in Visual Studio?

Comment: @PastorCortes I actually did come across something that did that, it was something along the lines of https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/ combined with a visual studio auto-reload https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22800/file-edited-outside-vs-is-reloaded-without-prompt.html
but my personal experience of it at the time was bad, it may have improved :)