# How do I (re-)enable real-time CSS editing in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015:

1. Create a new empty C# ASP.NET web application (Framework 4.6).
2. Add `WebForm1.aspx`:

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
       <link href="mycss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>Hello World</div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Add `mycss.css`:

   ```
   div { color: red; }
   ```
4. Right-click on `WebForm1.aspx` and choose "Set As Start Page".
5. Click the "Run" button with "Google Chrome" selected as the browser.
6. Open mycss.css in Visual Studio and change `red` to `blue`.

Note that *the moment you finish typing `blue`*, the color in Chrome changes to blue. No saving in Visual Studio required, no reload in Chrome required. This [feature is awesome](https://www.dovetail.ie/blog/2016/visual-studio-2015-live-css-editing/#.Wd40b2iCxzw)!

Now do the same in Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.5). Nothing happens. I have to *save the CSS file* and *reload the browser page* to see the change.

How do I get that feature back? Is this some configuration option? Or a deliberately deprecated feature? Or a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called *Browser Link* and is part of Visual Studio. Make sure the feature is enabled and that "Enable CSS Auto-Sync" is turned on. [See here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink#how-to-use-browser-link). This page relates to .Net Core, but should still be relevant for WebForms.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's it! It's hard to google for some feature until you know it's official name.

Comment: I had to also switch off "Enable Reload on Save" to make the changes I was making smooth and real-time.